# c# Why stackpanel don't resize?

Tags: c#, silverlight, grid, silverlight-5.0, stackpanel

I am using silverlight and have to code in c# not xaml and i have a grid (myGrid) with 1 row and 1 column. This Grid further contain Border(`rect`) and this rect contains another grid (`childGrid`)inside having 1 row and 3 columns.

And this smallGrid further contains a stackpanel (sp) in second column whose size formed dynamically but smallGrid dont resize according to the growing size of stackpanel sp.

My code is like this:

```
   Grid myGrid = new Grid();
   myGrid.Width = 750;
   myGrid.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
   myGrid.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
   myGrid.ShowGridLines = false;

   ColumnDefinition colDef1 = new ColumnDefinition();
   myGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(colDef1);
   RowDefinition rowDef1 = new RowDefinition();
   myGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(rowDef1);


   Border rect = new Border();
   rect.Width = g.Width;
   rect.Height = g.Height;
   rect.BorderThickness = new Thickness(2);
   rect.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGray);

   Grid childGrid = new Grid();
   ColumnDefinition colDef1 = new ColumnDefinition();
   ColumnDefinition colDef2 = new ColumnDefinition();
   ColumnDefinition colDef3 = new ColumnDefinition();
   childGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(colDef1);
   childGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(colDef2);
   childGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(colDef3);


   int NumberOfRadioButton = 0;
   StackPanel sp = new StackPanel();

   foreach(var item in param.Component.Attributes.Items) {
       NumberOfRadioButton++;
       RadioButton rb = new RadioButton();
       rb.GroupName = item;
       rb.Content = item;
       sp.Children.Add(rb);

   }
   Grid.SetRow(sp, 1);
   Grid.SetColumn(sp, 1);
   childGrid.Height = sp.Height;
   childGrid.Children.Add(sp);

   TextBlock txtblk1ShowStatus = new TextBlock();
   TextBlock txtblkLabel = new TextBlock();

   txtblkLabel.Text = param.Label;
   Grid.SetColumn(txtblkLabel, 0);
   Grid.SetRow(txtblkLabel, 1);
   childGrid.Children.Add(txtblkLabel);

   txtblk1ShowStatus.Text = param.Name;
   Grid.SetColumn(txtblk1ShowStatus, 2);
   Grid.SetRow(txtblk1ShowStatus, 1);
   childGrid.Children.Add(txtblk1ShowStatus);

   rect.Child = childGrid;
   Grid.SetRow(rect, 1);
   myGrid.Children.Add(rect);
```

The size of `myGrid` and `childGrid` must grow dynamically according to the increasing stackpanel size on dynamically created radio buttons? Because all the radio buttons are not displayed in column 2 please see the last radiobutton in snapshot belowis not displayed because of border crossing ("Very High", just after "High"):
[image]

EDIT: I even tried these 3 steps but it still the same:
(1)Remove rect.Width = g.Width; rect.Height = g.Height; childGrid.Height = sp.Height;

(2)add rowdef.Height= new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto);(because i am expanding vertically)

(3) add sp.Orientation = Orientation.Vertical;

Edit2 : myGrid is liek this:

```
            Grid myGrid = new Grid();
            myGrid.Width = 750;       
            myGrid.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
            myGrid.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
            myGrid.ShowGridLines = false;

            ColumnDefinition colDef1 = new ColumnDefinition();
            myGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(colDef1);       
            int totalRows = p.Parameter.Count() + p.Separator.Count();

            for (int i = 0; i < totalRows; i++)
            {
                myGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());

            }
```

EDIT3: (my changed code after bit's suggestion)

```
  Border rect = new Border();
// rect.Width = g.Width;
// rect.Height = g.Height;
    rect.BorderThickness = new Thickness(2);
    rect.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGray);

    Grid childGrid = new Grid();
    ColumnDefinition colDef1 = new ColumnDefinition();
    ColumnDefinition colDef2 = new ColumnDefinition();
    ColumnDefinition colDef3 = new ColumnDefinition();
    RowDefinition rowdef = new RowDefinition();
    childGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(colDef1);
    childGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(colDef2);
    childGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(colDef3);

    childGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(rowdef);
    rowdef.Height= new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto);

     int NumberOfRadioButton =0;
     StackPanel sp = new StackPanel();
     sp.Orientation = Orientation.Vertical;

     foreach (var item in param.Component.Attributes.Items)
     {                 
         NumberOfRadioButton++;
         RadioButton rb = new RadioButton();
         rb.GroupName = item;
         rb.Content = item;
         sp.Children.Add(rb);

     }
    Grid.SetRow(sp, LoopCount);
    Grid.SetColumn(sp, 1);
    childGrid.ShowGridLines = true;
 //   rect.Height = double.NaN;
    childGrid.Children.Add(sp);

    TextBlock txtblk1ShowStatus = new TextBlock();
    TextBlock txtblkLabel = new TextBlock();

    txtblkLabel.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Center;
    txtblkLabel.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Center;
    txtblkLabel.TextAlignment = System.Windows.TextAlignment.Center;
    txtblkLabel.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
    txtblkLabel.FontSize = 15;
    txtblkLabel.FontStyle = FontStyles.Normal;
    txtblkLabel.Padding = new Thickness(5, 10, 5, 10);

    txtblkLabel.Text = param.Label;
    Grid.SetColumn(txtblkLabel, 0);
    Grid.SetRow(txtblkLabel, LoopCount);
    childGrid.Children.Add(txtblkLabel);

    txtblk1ShowStatus.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Center;
    txtblk1ShowStatus.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Center;
    txtblk1ShowStatus.TextAlignment = System.Windows.TextAlignment.Center;
    txtblk1ShowStatus.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
    txtblk1ShowStatus.FontSize = 15;
    txtblk1ShowStatus.FontStyle = FontStyles.Normal;
    txtblk1ShowStatus.Padding = new Thickness(5, 10, 5, 10);

    txtblk1ShowStatus.Text = param.Name;
    Grid.SetColumn(txtblk1ShowStatus, 2);
    Grid.SetRow(txtblk1ShowStatus, LoopCount);
    childGrid.Children.Add(txtblk1ShowStatus);

    rect.Child = childGrid;
    Grid.SetRow(rect, LoopCount);
    myGrid.Children.Add(rect);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a bunch of things you need to consider here..

In case you want a Horizontally expanding `smallGrid`, set the

```
sp.Orientation=Orientation.Horizontal
```

Then set the widths of the columns in `smallGrid` to Auto.

```
colDef.Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto); // Auto
```

You don't really need the `myGrid`, directly using the `Border` should suffice.

Get rid of assigning the Height s eg:

```
rect.Width = g.Width;
rect.Height = g.Height;
childGrid.Height = sp.Height;
```

Else, if you wanted a vertically expanding smallGrid, make sure the parent of the `Border rect` (or myGrid, in case you decide to keep it), allows for expansion Height (mostly check that height is not hard coded to a fix number or something)

Also, set the

```
smallGrid.ShowGridLines = true;
```

to give you a better idea in regards to what is actually taking up the space.

Lastly, do this too

```
int totalRows = p.Parameter.Count() + p.Separator.Count(); 

for (int i = 0; i < totalRows; i++) 
{ 
var rowDef=new RowDefinition(); 
rowdef.Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto); 
myGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(rowDef); 

}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. As i understand from you: (1)Remove rect.Width = g.Width;
rect.Height = g.Height;
childGrid.Height = sp.Height; (2)add rowdef.Height= new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto);(because i am expanding vertically) (3) add  sp.Orientation = Orientation.Vertical; BUT STILL NOT WORKING; ITS STILL THE SAME

Comment: Can you show the code for the parent container of myGrid?

Comment: you can see my full edited code for myGrid and childGrid and  stackpanel now . I have updated.

Comment: are you able to figure out something? or do you wanna give anyother suggestion ?

Comment: i think the problem is due to this line : for (int i = 0; i < totalRows; i++)
            {
                myGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());

            }   because here the row heigght is not set auto. DONT YOU THINK SO ?

Comment: give it a try...

What is the parent of myGrid?

Comment: myGrid is the parent of border.It has no parent

Comment: myGrid is the Parent of Border and Border is parent oc childGrid and childGrid is the parent of stackPanel(sp) in second column.

Comment: I just created poc App to test your code, it works perfectly fine.
your original code too..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54506/discussion-between-bit-and-user234839).

Comment: var rowDef=new RowDefinition(); 
rowdef.Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto); 
myGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(rowDef)   worked for me